# How can I verify that a protocol defines a selector at runtime?

Tags: objective-c

Given a selector

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorWithString(someSelectorName);
```

and a protocol:

```
Protocol protocol = NSProtocolFromString(someProtocolName);
```

how would i check that the selector defined in the protocol?

```
BOOL hasSelector = protocolHasSelector(protocol, selector);
```

Comment: minus one, huh? This is why I shy away from asking questions here. I just don't know what people are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Objective-C runtime provides a function named [`protocol_getMethodDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/protocol_getMethodDescription).  You can use this to determine whether a protocol defines a selector:

> **Return Value**
>
> An `objc_method_description` structure that describes the method specified by *aSel*, *isRequiredMethod*, and *isInstanceMethod* for the protocol *p*.
>
> If the protocol does not contain the specified method, returns an `objc_method_description` structure with the value `{NULL, NULL}`.

To use this function, you must `#import <objc/runtime.h>` or `@import ObjectiveC`.

Note that you may need to call the method up to four times, with each combination of values for `isRequiredMethod` and `isInstanceMethod`.  If you only care about instance methods (not class methods), you may still want to call it twice (once with `YES` for `isRequiredMethod` and one with `NO`).